# Mounting partition as a virtual disk in Windows?

Tags: windows-8, windows-xp, mount, virtual-disk

I'm trying to mount a partition which contains a whole MBR partition table as a virtual disk on Windows, but I haven't found any soulutions for that.

Here's how I do it in Linux:
With `fdisk -lu /dev/sdc2` I get the offset to the partition I want to mount.

```
losetup /dev/loop0 /dev/sdc2 -o 32256
mount -t vfat /dev/loop0 /media/marcus/WESTERNDIGI
```

I tried using diskpart, but it just errors:

```
> diskpart
DISKPART> select volume 2
DISKPART> assign
DISKPART> create vdisk FILE=\\.\H:
DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

I have searched the whole event log, but I was unable to find anything related to this.

Is it possible to mount a volume/partition on Windows as a block device, like you do with mknod/losetup on Linux?

Comment: Are you trying to solve this on  both a windows 8 host and a windows XP host? (ignore what is in the virtual disk as I do not see how the guest OS has any influence on this).

Comment: Yes, I was able to get Win8 running on my ancient laptop using an external harddrive using ImageX, but the laptop's internal harddrive has Windows Experience ServicePack 3 on it.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it can't be fully done yet on Windows, but here are the steps to do it:

1. Boot into Linux
2. Execute `fdisk -lu /dev/sdc2` (where `sdc2` is the partition you want to access) to find out the offset to the partition you want to access, and write it down
3. On Windows open `diskmgmt.msc` from the Run menu
4. Assign a letter to the partition that contains the partition table (in this example it's `H:`)
5. Install [ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/)
6. In the "image file" textbox, type in `\\.\H:`, where `H:` is the letter you assigned to the partition
7. In the "image file offset" textbox write the offset you calculated from step#2
8. If your version of ImDisk is affected by a bug, then click into the "size of the virtual disk" textbox, then click into another textbox (the "size of the virtual disk" textbox should contain the text "(existing image file size)")
9. If it's not selected by default, set the offset unit to bytes
10. Select the "virtual disk drive accesses image file directly" radiobox
11. Click OK to mount the partition